# tex4ht error when using --lua and luatex85 with datetime package

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, texlive-2016

I had a problem with using `datetime` with lualatex under TL 2016. Thanks to the answer [datetime-package-does-not-work-with-lualatex-in-tl-2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315198/datetime-package-does-not-work-with-lualatex-in-tl-2016) the solution solved the issue when compiling with lualatex. But now it fails with tex4ht. So I thought it is best to open new question on this since it is different systems.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%ext
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}%only do this when TL 2016
{
\usepackage{luatex85}
\edef\pdfcreationdate{\pdffeedback creationdate}
}
{}
\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime}
\begin{document}
\currenttime
\end{document}
```

The above compiles ok and no errors, with `lualatex` under TL 2016, but gives an error with `make4ht` under the `lua` option, which uses lualatex.

```
  make4ht --lua foo.tex
  ......
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty)
! unexpected use of \pdffeedback.
\reserved@a ...def \pdfcreationdate {\pdffeedback 
                                                  creationdate} 
l.7 {}

?
```

I compile all my latex file using lualatex and tex4ht. And the above package worked with no problem with both in TL 2015.

This is new TL 2016, installed today.

Here is file list

```
File List*
 scrbook.cls    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (type area)
luatex85.sty    2016/05/23 v1.2 pdftex aliases for luatex
datetime.sty    2015/03/20 v2.60 Date Time Package
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
fmtcount.sty    2015/05/05 v3.01
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
fcprefix.sty    2012/09/28
fcnumparser.sty    2012/09/28
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
fc-english.def    2013/08/17
datetime-defaults.sty    2013/09/10
```

Complete console listing:

```
make4ht --lua foo.tex
Output dir:     
Compiler:   dvilualatex
Latex options:   -jobname=foo 
tex4ht.sty :    xhtml,
tex4ht  
build_file  foo.mk4
Cannot open config file foo.mk4
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param ext
Adding:     ext dvi
LaTeX call: dvilualatex  -jobname=foo  '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,.a.b.c.\input foo'
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(./foo.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty)
! unexpected use of \pdffeedback.
\reserved@a ...def \pdfcreationdate {\pdffeedback 
                                                  creationdate} 
l.7 {}

?
```

And this is the complete console output from `lualatex`, no errors:

```
lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fmtcount.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fcprefix.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fcnumparser.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fc-english.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime-defaults.sty))
(./foo.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex
.map}] (./foo.aux))
 364 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 6 glue, 44 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:28,3:2,4:1,5:13,6:29,7:23,8:2,9:12,11:3
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 11263 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update to the latest version of `luatex85` package and remove:

```
\edef\pdfcreationdate{\pdffeedback creationdate}
```

`\pdfcreationdate` is (now) defined in a way compatible with `dviluatex`.

Comment: @Nasser perhaps your mirror is taking a while to catch up. your latex format is not updated to patch level 1, and luatex85.sty should be version `[2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex]`